# convert from enum to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, enums

Can you help me hww to corect this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace NTSoftHRM
{

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class EnumValueList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        public EnumValueList()
        {
            IEnumerable<T> enumValues = GetEnumValues();
            foreach ( T enumValue in enumValues )
            {
                enumItems.Add( enumValue );
            }
        } // EnumValueList

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected Type EnumType
        {
            get { return typeof( T ); }
        } // EnumType

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return enumItems.GetEnumerator();
           // return ((IEnumerable<T>)enumItems).GetEnumerator();

        } // GetEnumerator

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        } // GetEnumerator

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // no Enum.GetValues() in Silverlight
        private IEnumerable<T> GetEnumValues()
        {
            List<T> enumValue = new List<T>();

            Type enumType = EnumType;

            return Enum.GetValues(enumType);

        } // GetEnumValues

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // members
        private readonly List<T> enumItems = new List<T>();

    } // class EnumValueList

}
```

when bulid the error is:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) at  return Enum.GetValues(enumType)

Comment: From the error message: "are you missing a cast?" Yes, you are missing a cast. Pay attention to what error messages tell you.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The issue is in your `GetEnumValues` method, [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an `Array` not an `IEnumerable<T>`. You need to cast it i.e.

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).Cast<EnumType>();
```

Comment: Does `System.Array` implement `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: The concrete array returned from `Enum.GetValues` will have type `T[]`, which derives from `System.Array` and implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @JakubKonecki yep, as of .NET 2.0 - see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).

Comment: Maybe a bit more concise code:
`Enum.GetValues(enumType).AsEnumerable()`

Comment: @florien saving a char...also think you mean `AsEnumerable<T>()`

Comment: @James you dont need <T> there as the generic type is automatically infered by the compiler. Yeah, not much shorter, but if you have to use it in a longer expression, it may be more practical. Consider this:
`((IEnumerable<T>)Enum.GetValues(enumType)).Select(/*some stuff*/)` vs `Enum.GetValues(enumType).AsEnumerable().Select(/*some stuff*/)`.Less parentheses, etc, anyway, it was just a notice for an alternative form... :)

Comment: @florien: `Enum.GetValues(enumType).AsEnumerable()` leads to an error _CS1061:  'Array' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' ..._ - Which usings did you use?

Comment: Hi! Yes, sorry, you must add using for System.Linq!

Comment: @florien: even with the `using System.Linq` it's still `error BC30456: 'AsEnumerable' is not a member of 'Array'`.  Using `.Cast(Of enumType)()` does make it an `IEnumerable()` and is the most concise.

Comment: @RossPresser Yeah, that’s right, somehow I saw it totally wrong, I would definitely use that solution now! So the best way: Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).Cast<EnumType>(), just how in the answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
    private IEnumerable<T> GetEnumValues()
    {
        Type enumType = EnumType;

        return Enum.GetValues(enumType).ToList<T>();
    }
```

Comment: `ToList` is not necessary here, `Array` already supports `IEnumerable<T>` it just needs a cast.

Comment: @James - just to be precise `System.Array` *doesn't* implement `IEnumerable<T>`, it implements `IEnumerable`. `T[]` *does* implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @JakupKonecki it implements `IEnumerable` at *compile* time, it then implements `IEnumerable<T>` at runtime - it's stated in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this line is the one throwing the error?:

```
return Enum.GetValues(enumType);
```

According to the error message, you're missing a cast.  Did you try adding a cast?:

```
return Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<T>();
```

The `.GetValues()` method on `Enum` returns [an `Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx).  And though it is something over which you can enumerate (it implements `IEnumerable`), it is not a generic enumeration (it *does not* implement `IEnumerable<T>` at compile time, though [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) indicates that it will be available at runtime.).

In order to return an `IEnumerable` as an `IEnumerable<T>` you need to cast it.  Since collections aren't always directly covariant, there's a handy `.Cast<T>()` method provided to transform the collection.

Comment: That isn't a cast, that's a method call where the method happens to be named "Cast". (It should compile and do the right thing, though.)

Comment: "*it does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`*" - that's funny, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) say otherwise...

Comment: I have try as you recommend but it not compile

Comment: @James: That indeed is interesting, because I would have expected more flexibility in that case.  I guess my explanation isn't entirely accurate then.  Though this statement is probably the issue: `"The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools."`  The error is a compile-time error, where the interface isn't known to the compiler.  But since it implements the interface at runtime, your direct cast works just as well.

Comment: @chungphamnhu: Is there a specific compiler error?  "It [does] not compile" isn't particularly helpful I'm afraid...

Comment: @David: compile Error 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @chungphamnhu: Maybe you need `using System.Linq`?  Again, the error message is pretty clear about this.  `Enumerable.Cast<T>` is in the `System.Linq` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the generic overload of the [Enum.GetValues() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-8.0#system-enum-getvalues-1). Requires .NET 5+ and no need to cast:

```cs
IEnumerable<Items> items = Enum.GetValues<Items>();
```

where `Items` is the enum type.